# Error 0x2 starting php.exe --version

Tags: php

i am getting this strange error while i check my php version

> Error 0x2 starting php.exe --version

can anyone tell me how to solve it ?

Comment: What's your OS, where did you get PHP, etc...

Comment: windows 7  , my php folder is in c:wamp/bin/php/php.exe

Comment: Sounds like a corrupted binary. You might want to re-install. Does PHP work for uses other than `--version`?

Comment: yeah it works fine  i have no problem rather thin this one , i cannot install composer or anything on cmd

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your `php.exe` is in your PATH.

Here is a good resource for setting PATH variables : http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

After that restart your console and try again.