# Error 0x2 starting php.exe in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.4

I am suddenly got this error in my composer when I am using **php artisan** and I already find this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503348/error-0x2-starting-php-exe-version) but it doesn't help me  , How can I fix it, I am using laravel 5.4 and PHP 7.1 and IIS 7.5 as my server

[image]

Comment: What to you get if you run `php -r "echo 'It works!';"`?

Comment: Did you try this command outside Git bash? In the Windows console.

Comment: @TobiasF. its say bash: !': event not found

Comment: @AnthonyB - I try it right now and its say 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Please try giving the full path of `php.exe`. In both environments, Git bash and Windows console.

Comment: I don't know why that error its suddenly appear, its work fine before

Comment: It's possible that PHP has been removed from the PATH by an other program, or a conflict between Git bash and Windows, etc. But with the absolute path to PHP, does it work?

Comment: @AnthonyB - If the PHP remove from the PATH how can I repath the PHP and Git bash again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177787/discussion-between-anthonyb-and-mathew-magante).